# How Did I Lose 1,000 Points In A Day On SO?

Tags: support

I logged into SO this morning and found that I'd somehow lost 1,000 of my reputation points overnight.  There's no indication of what happened or why.  How can I get an explanation?  Thanks.

Comment: I got a recalc yesterday, coincidence?  Check http://stackoverflow.com/reputation to see if the number matches.  That never happens, if it is equal then you got a recalc too.

Comment: I got a recalc - it matches my current total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the automated jobs saw a distinct pattern of voting - perhaps some well-meaning user voting *excessively* for your account. Those votes were cancelled. I stress that this is automated, not a personal thing - more details [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/) and [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) - and those aren't meant in an *accusatory* tone - I'm just explaining why that process *exists*.

I'll take a quick look to see if there is an obvious reason...

Comment: I doubt that.  I don't accumulate that many points in any given day.

Comment: @user131628 - they don't have to be from one day; I've looked and I can't see anything *too* obvious (but then: you can't once it has been revoked).

Comment: Why should I be penalized for somebody else's voting habits?  How many times has Jon Skeet lost points because of adoring fan boys who vote his every utterance up?

Comment: If something else is going on, please do let me know.